# What is The Correct Way To Delete A has_one Association From a Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-one

I have a `NewsItem` model which `has_one :photo`. I would like to allow a user to quickly delete this association from a link (without having to use an *Edit NewsItem* form).

What is the correct way to delete this association from a link without adding an extra controller action just for this purpose?

Edit: I already have the 7 standard CRUD actions on my NewsItemController. I don't want to add a new action just for this case.

Comment: Do you want to delete `news_item` or associated `photo` or both ?

Comment: without a controller action it would be impossible

Comment: @Pavan I just want to delete the association (the `Photo`).

Comment: @YuryLebedev It's not that I don't want to use a controller action. Just that I don't want to add an action just to deal with this case. I have the 7 standard actions already on my `NewsItem` model.

Comment: You can have normal `link_to` and in the controller in the destroy method change `@news_item.destroy` to `@news_item.photo.destroy`

Comment: @Pavan That is a terrible solution. How would I destroy a `NewsItem`?

Comment: Ok. You can place `@news_item.destroy` after the `@news_item.photo.destroy` for that. Yes thats a terrible idea but without a new controller action,this far you can get.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to send delete request to a controller#action

in action you can simple do

```
  news_item = NewsItem.find(params[:news_item_id])
  news_item.photo.destroy
```

to build a destroy link

```
link_to 'Destroy Photo', news_items_photo_path(news_item, news_item.photo), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to delete an ActiveRecord association from a controller. I'm asking how to create a link that deletes the association using the existing Restful actions.

Comment: link you can build like - 

    link_to 'Destroy Photo', news_items_photo_path(news_item, news_item.photo), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete